# Two ISR's on Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino, isr

I'm writing some code for a homework assignment, and part of the assignment is to have a 16x2 LCD display a clock that shows how long the arduino has been on for. This clock needs to run off a timer interrupt. I have gotten that part working, but the second part of the assignment is to have another interrupt (an external button as the signal) that will reset the clock to all 0's. Currently the ISR doesn't seem to do anything. Any ideas?

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <TimerOne.h>

int buttonPin = 2;
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 6, 5, 4, 3);
int secs, tens, minutes, tenminutes, hours, tenhours;
volatile long counter = 0;

void setup() {
  Timer1.initialize(100000);
  Timer1.attachInterrupt(timerISR);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(0, buttonPressISR, CHANGE);
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("0");
  lcd.setCursor(1,1);
  lcd.print("0");
  lcd.setCursor(2, 1);
  lcd.print(":");
  lcd.setCursor(3,1);


lcd.print("0");
  lcd.setCursor(4,1);
  lcd.print("0");
  lcd.setCursor(5, 1);
  lcd.print(":");
  lcd.setCursor(6,1);
  lcd.print("0");
  lcd.setCursor(7,1);
  lcd.print("0");

}

void loop() {
  secs = (counter/10) % 10;
  tens = (counter/100) % 6;
  minutes = (counter/600) %10;
  tenminutes = (counter/6000) %6;
  hours = (counter/36000) %10;
  tenhours = (counter/360000) %10;
  lcd.setCursor(7, 1);
  lcd.print(secs);
  lcd.setCursor(6,1);
  lcd.print(tens);
  lcd.setCursor(4, 1);
  lcd.print(minutes);
  lcd.setCursor(3, 1);
  lcd.print(tenminutes);
  lcd.setCursor(1, 1);
  lcd.print(hours);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print(tenhours);

}

void buttonPressISR() {
  counter = 0;
}

void timerISR() {
  counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know there is an Arduino Stack Exchange beta site for  Arduino questions?

I can't see any obvious errors in the code. Are you aware that interrupt pin 0 on the code is actually the digital pin 2 on the Arduino?

Comment: Huh, I thought I was on the arduino stack exchange. Must have messed up the submitting of the question. Also, I am aware that pin 2 is interrupt 0 - I have buttonPin assigned to 2, and the interrupt for it assigned as 0.

Comment: OK Maybe start debugging by setting the LED pin high inside the buttonPressISR function, then you can at least see if it's a problem with your interrupt or your timing algorithm.

Comment: Also if you can set the baud rate to one compatible with the serial monitor I would send 'counter' out via Serial.println to see what's going on.

Comment: baud rate? Sorry I'm a little bit new to all of this. The LED is a good idea, implementing that now.

Comment: Actually I just tried it, I don't have a button, just a jumper from my breadboard to my arduino, and when I connected pin 2 to ground it acted as if it had been changed. I was trying to connect it to 5v to get a change out of it.

Comment: Ah ok, you seem to be knowledgable so I assumed you knew. Baud rate is the speed your Arduinos clock will run the programme at. When using the serial monitor in the Arduino IDE you need to have it set to the same speed as the sketch baud rate in order to view the text.

Comment: OK that makes sense. It's looking for a change after the sketch has started. If it doesn't see one it won't do anything.